# Easy way to sort multiline paragraph where only first lines begin with non-space?

Tags: shell, sorting, command-line, multiline, paragraph

I have a text or log file which typically looks like this:

```
First line which is also a paragraph.
Another line that is its own paragraph.
etc. etc.
```

but occasionally it has some spill-over into a multi-line paragrah:

```
First line which is also a paragraph.
Another line that is its own paragraph.
Now, this paragraph encompasses more than a single line
    with its second line onwards being indented by spaces
    to distinguish it from the paragraph-opener, although
    it could just as well have been tabs etc.
And this is another paragraph.
```

I would like to sort these paragraphs lexicographically; and I don't mind if it's by the first line only or the entire paragraph. If these were one-liner paragraphs - then Bob's your uncle, we got `sort`. But what do I do otherwise?

I know that, in principle, I could:

1. Define an escaping scheme
2. Escape newlines which are followed by white space (and escape the escaping character itself)
3. Sort the resulting one-line-per-paragraph file
4. Un-escape

but this seems a bit cumbersome. Can I do better?

Notes:

- I realize this is doable in a straightforward way using an awk or perl script, but the closer an answer is to a one-liner, the better.
- You may make reasonable assumptions in your answer, such as the GNU variants of certain tools, or POSIX compatibility, or minimum versions of tools etc. But - please make them explicitly.

Comment: Is using Perl or Awk or Python acceptable?

Comment: @tripleee: See edit. If you can make it short and sweet then go for it :-)

Answer (score 2):

A few ways:

A one-liner pipeline that uses `perl` to read the entire file, and insert a 0 byte between paragraphs (Defined as a newline immediately followed by a non-whitespace character), `sort` to sort them, and finally `tr` to remove those 0 bytes again from the final output. Basically a simpler version of your idea.

```bash
perl -0777 -pe 's/^(?=\S)/\0/gm'  | sort -z | tr -d '\0'
```

(Does require a version of `sort` that understands the `-z` option)

---

Or a pure perl one-liner that's a bit more verbose but does it all in one process without a pipeline or needing non-POSIX `sort` options:

```bash
perl -ne 'if (/^\s/) { $lines[-1] .= $_ } else { push @lines, $_ }
          END { print for sort @lines }' input.txt
```

Similar approach using GNU `awk` instead:

```
gawk '/^[^[:space:]]/ { lineno++ }
      { lines[lineno] = lines[lineno] $0 "\n" }
      END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
        for (lineno in lines)
          printf("%s", lines[lineno])
      }' input.txt
```

---

Or if you're okay installing extra stuff, I found a nifty looking program written in `perl` called [`ptp`](https://metacpan.org/dist/App-PTP/view/script/ptp) (Install through your OS package manager if available or with `cpan App::PTP`/`cpanm App::PTP`/other preferred CPAN client):

```bash
ptp --input-separator '\n(?=\S)' --sort input.txt
```

Comment: I wonder... can I effect this `\0` insertion with sed?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know of a way to generate nul bytes in sed commands. But using a loop to get each separate paragraph into the pattern buffer is probably doable.

Comment: Hmm. Use sed to combine multiline paragraphs into a single line, sort those, and then use a tool that wraps long lines to get the original indented form back?

Comment: Added a different perl one-liner that doesn't need to insert or strip out nul bytes.

Comment: You can't do those null byte shenanigans _portably_ with `sed`. If you are willing to restrict yourself to only e.g. GNU `sed` then yes; but then Perl is probably more ubiquitous and portable in practice.

Comment: @tripleee I saw a comment on another question today where the asker said they didn't have perl installed. I just about cried. This modern computing world is strange and I don't think I like it.

Comment: There will always be embedded environments where all you have is a rusty nail and some chewing gum. I don't envy the tradeoff; increase your attack surface through additional dependencies, or write your own (probably initially buggy and insecure) implementation from scratch in a low-level language?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using GNU `sed`. The null bytes make this unlikely to be portable to other `sed` variants (and the `-z` option to many commands to handle null-separated input is also a GNU extension).

```bash
sed -E 's/^(\S)/\x00\1/' |
sort -z |
tr -d '\000'
```

You will notice the similarities to the Perl solution.

The escapes `\x00` and `\S` are not generally available in `sed`. Many `sed` implementations specifically choke on null bytes, even if you somehow managed to insert a null byte.

The `-E` option is also nonstandard, though rather widely supported. It enables a somewhat more convenient and familiar regex syntax than the crude default BRE. (In concrete terms, we don't have to backslash the capturing parentheses.)

Tested on Debian 11 (Bullseye); GNU `sed` 4.7.

---

Here's a variant which I managed to get to work on MacOS. It assumes you have no literal escape characters in your input. (It also requires you to replace the `^[` with a literal escape character; in many shells you can do this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>; or, of course, write the script in an editor and then run it.)

```
sed -n -e 's/^\([[:space:]]\)/^[\1/' -e H -e '$!d' \
    -e 'x' -e 's/\n^[/^[/g' -ep |
sort | sed 's/^[/\n/g'
```

This collects the entire file into the hold space of `sed`, so it will probably not work very well for large files.

In brief, if the first character is a whitespace character, prepend an escape character. The `H` command appends the current line to the hold space. `$!d` says if this is not the last input line, delete this line and start over. If we fall through, we are at the end of the file; copy the entire file from the hold space back into the pattern space `x` and replace any newline before an escape character with just an escape character, and print it all out.

At this point, what you have are lines where the internal newlines have been replaced with an escape character; and so the regular `sort` works fine.

Finally, we put back the newlines where the escape characters were.

I believe the support for `\n` should be reasonably ubiquitous, but there might be really old `sed` versions which require further modifications around that. (If they are *that* old, they also might not support the POSIX character class notation `[[:space:]]`. I guess you can replace it with `[     ]` where the second character is a literal tab character).

Comment: Your first `sed` solution is much simpler (and more efficient) than anything I could think of!  Concerning the null byte portability issue, would it be a viable workaround to use `\r` instead then convert it to null with `tr`, like `sed -E 's/^(\S)/\r\1/' | tr '\r' '\000'`?

Comment: @Grobu The `\S` is also not portable, and even the `-E` option is non-POSIX. The second solution could certainly use a literal carriage return instead of Esc, I suppose (though then it won't work on Windows text files; but then if someone chose or was forced to use Windows, they probably already don't expect anything to work). Also, doubtful whether `sort` will reliably ignore carriage return, or regard it as an alternate line terminator, or something else. But if you have `sort -z` but not GNU `sed`, that's a workaround (though I doubt that's a common scenario).